# Solve the system of differential equations over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following system

$$\dot x = A x$$

where

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 3 &-2\\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

I want to solve this over $\mathbb{R}$. However, the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors of $A$ are in $\mathbb{C}.$ Over the complex field, the solution should be as follows

$$x(t) = \alpha e^{(2+i)t}\begin{pmatrix}1+i\\1\end{pmatrix} + \beta e^{(2-i)t}\begin{pmatrix}1-i\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$.

How do I find an equivalent solution to this ODE in $\mathbb{R}$? Should I use the following isomorphism?

$$(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto x_1 + i x_2 \in \mathbb{C}$$

Or should I take the real part of the equation?

Comment: If $f$ is a complex solution of a real differential system, then so are ${\rm Re}(f)$ and ${\rm Im}(f)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have complex conjugate eigenvalues /eigenvectors and can make use of either one for the solution

$e^{\lambda_1 t}v_1 = e^{(2+i)t}\begin{bmatrix}1+i\\1\end{bmatrix} = e^{2t}e^{it}\begin{bmatrix}1+i\\1\end{bmatrix} = e^{2t}(\cos t + i \sin t)\begin{bmatrix}1+i\\1\end{bmatrix} = e^{2t}\begin{bmatrix} (\cos t - \sin  t) +  i ( \cos t +\sin  t)\\ \cos t + i\sin t \end{bmatrix} $

Because the real and imaginary parts are both independent solutions, we can now write

$$X(t) = \begin{bmatrix}x(t)\\ y(t) \end{bmatrix} =  e^{2t}\left(c_1\begin{bmatrix}\cos t - \sin  t \\ \cos t \end{bmatrix} + c_2 \begin{bmatrix} \cos t+\sin t\\ \sin t \end{bmatrix}\right)$$